# how to find the time at which modified string will be equal to original string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, c++14

How to solve a question where the string is first circularly rotated by 1 letter, then by 2 letter  and soon , at what time the modified string will be equal to original string? these strings are made up using 'a' and 'b' only.

for eg: aabaab is the string on first letter rotation it will become abaaba on second rotation it will become aabaab so answer is 2.

I tried to solve this question but could only do this only by brute force.
https://pasteboard.co/HwWR6WZ.png

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Posting code _here_ adds value to this question.

Comment: And what is wrong with your brute-force attempt?

Comment: Does the 2nd rotation effectively rotated string by 3 characters or by 2? When you say "*the string is first circularly rotated by 1 letter, then by 2 letter and soon*" it is not clear whether at 2nd step you rotate original or the one from the previous step. This changes answer.

Comment: after first rotation string is rotated by 1 letter, suppose you have aaab then after 1st rotation string becomes aaba, then in second rotation you will pick up starting two letters of the "present" string (which is "aa" from "aaba") then rotated it, so it will become "baaa" then in the 3rd turn you will pick 3 starting letters of the present string (which is "baa") then rotate it, so it will become "abaa" then in 4th turn you will rotate it by 4 letters of the present string so this will become  "aaba" in the 5th turn you will need to rotate it by (5)mod(length of string) letters

Comment: mod is to be only taken if the turn is greater than length of string and turn is not a multiple of string length. if Turn is multiple of string length then use rotate it by string length. Hope this help!!

Answer (score 1):

Let `s` be the original string, what you want is the smallest index `i > 0` such that `s` is a substring at index `i` in the string `ss`. You can construct the [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree#CITEREFGusfield1999) of `ss` then search `s` in this tree. This algorithm runs in O(n) time.

For example, consider `s = abab`, the suffix tree of `ss`, i.e. `abababab` looks like (`$` represents the end of a string)

```
           root
        ab/    \b
         /      \
      ab/\$    $/\ab
       /  \    /  \
      *    6  7  $/\ab
   ab/\$         /  \
    /  \        5  $/\ab$ 
ab$/\$  4          /  \
  /  \            3    1
 0    2
```

After searching `abab` we reach the `*` node, and there are three leaves representing indices 0,2,4 in its subtree. The answer is the smallest positive index among them, i.e. 2.

The suffix tree [can be constructed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array#Suffix_tree_construction) using suffix array and LCP array in O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

Since the string contains only 'a' and 'b' you can represent them as bits with 1 and 0 s. Then circular shifting and doing a bit-wise operation like XOR might give you better performance.

Comment: I introduced a bit representation solution (in my "second solution").

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what you mean by brute force but I'd do it this way:

1. Concatenate original with itself to simulate cyclic bounduary conditions.
2. Search original within it's double, starting from the 2nd character.

It should work in the linear time, It's going to be `O(2*N)` tops. I've checked with [clang's substring find](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/f477af5fda63871733be081b7039f6850348e08f/include/__string#L652) it's going to go through searched string (i.e. cycled one) at most it's size.

It will find a match for sure at most at the `s.size()` because the string is doubled.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

auto steps(const string& s) {
    string cycled = s+s;
    return cycled.find(s, 1);
}

int main() {
    string s{"aabaab"};
    cout << steps(s) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I guess you could optimize for memory and some time by avoiding the copy and working only on the original string but you'd need to provide a custom iterator, that would cycle over the string. Then, it should be possible to fairly easy rewrite the algorithm from `std::basic_string`.

Comment: Oh. I think I might have misunderstood the problem. I'll wait for OP to clarify and correct this answer or delete it.